# Coq impact analysis

Tags: coq

Let's say I have several proofs based on data structure (or lemma) *A*. Then, I refactored *A* to *A'*, is there a general practice / tool facility for Coq to know **all** proofs are impacted by my refactoring?

Thank you for shedding some light on this matter.

edit1: thank you for all your suggestions, I will give them a try, and get back on this.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://proofengineering.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another tool that might be useful is [dpdgraph](https://github.com/karmaki/coq-dpdgraph), which makes it possible to display all the usage dependence between various objects.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such tool available, as far as I am aware. What I usually do is to refactor the code and try to repair it. Because of Coq's proofs and typing discipline, once the code compiles again, it is usually the case that it works.

Comment: Thank you. This what I currently do. but as the project getting bigger. I might lost of track of all things need to be change. I am thinking to do something like "regression test cases", that need to be run  on every modification.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [PUMPKIN PATCH](http://pumpkin.uwplse.org/) ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/uwplse/PUMPKIN-PATCH/)). Here's a quote from the project readme file:

> This is a prototype plugin for finding patches for broken Coq proofs. To use PUMPKIN, the programmer modifies a single proof script to provide an example adaptation of a proof to a change. PUMPKIN generalizes this example into a reusable patch which can be used to fix other broken proofs.

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but it might be of interest.